# Simulate a tabclick on tabscroller

Tags: javascript

I would like to use the url address bar(IE7 nad 8), for simulating a tab click.
Some parts of the html section for the webpage as follows. for the tabscroller, debugTabs-tabScroller, when the page opens, always the tab "Main" is selected. I would like to use the address url bar, using a js code so that "Debug Probe", tab is clicked. I tried the below(after the page is loaded) but doesnt seem to work.

```
javascript:document.getElementById('debugTabs-Probe-tab').click()
```

part of the html section.

```
var debugTabs = new dptabs.TabSet(
                    "debugTabs",
                    ["Main","Probe","Conformance"],
                    []
                );


.
....
...


<div id="genericDetailTabs" class="genericDetailTabs">
    <div id="debugTabs-tabSet" class="tabSet">
        <div id="debugTabs-tabScrollLeftArrow" class="tabScrollLeftArrow" onmouseover="debugTabs.startScroll(1);" onmouseout="debugTabs.stopScroll()" onmousedown="debugTabs.setScrollSpeed(2);" onmouseup="debugTabs.setScrollSpeed()">
        </div>
        <div id="debugTabs-tabScroller" class="tabScroller">
        <div class="tab" id="debugTabs-Main-tab" onclick="debugTabs.clickTab('Main');">
                <span class="tab-wrap-1">
            <span class="tab-wrap-2">
                    <span class="tab-wrap-3">Main</span>
            </span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="tab" id="debugTabs-Probe-tab" onclick="debugTabs.clickTab('Probe');">
            <span class="tab-wrap-1">
            <span class="tab-wrap-2">
                <span class="tab-wrap-3">Debug Probe</span>
            </span>
                </span>
        </div>
        <div class="tab" id="debugTabs-Conformance-tab" onclick="debugTabs.clickTab('Conformance');">
                <span class="tab-wrap-1">
            <span class="tab-wrap-2">
                <span class="tab-wrap-3">Conformance Validation</span>
            </span>
            </span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="debugTabs-tabScrollRightArrow" class="tabScrollRightArrow" onmouseover="debugTabs.startScroll(-1);" onmouseout="debugTabs.stopScroll()" onmousedown="debugTabs.setScrollSpeed(2);" onmouseup="debugTabs.setScrollSpeed()">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when and how are you calling the javascript code?

Comment: You don't have to use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol, JavaScript is the default script language since Netscape.

Comment: An example is, if we use gmail, after entering the userid and password, just replace the address bar with "javascript:document.getElementById('signIn').click()", will simulate the button click of signin.